# Adding some text to a view

Tags: android, animation, view

I am drawing a circle by using view and have animated the circle as well.Now i want to add a text in that circle with counter.For drawing the circle i wrote following code.

**Circle.java**

```
  public class Circle extends View {

private static final int START_ANGLE_POINT = 30;

private final Paint paint;
private final RectF rect;
private float angle;

public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    final int strokeWidth = 5;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    rect = new RectF(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, 100 + strokeWidth, 100 + strokeWidth);
    angle = 30;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, START_ANGLE_POINT, angle, false, paint);
}

public float getAngle() {
    return angle;
}

public void setAngle(float angle) {
    this.angle = angle;
}
}
```

And I am animating this view. Now I want to add a textview in the circle that I created.
I tried using

```
 new Canvas().drawText("",10,20,paint);
```

but it was of no use.Please help me in adding textview to this circular view.

Comment: Can you set the alignment of the text?

Comment: Yes.I set the alignment but the circle is still blank.

Comment: Color of the text?

Comment: how can i define the colour?

Comment: paint.setColor(Color.rgb(110, 110, 110));

Comment: Yes.I have already done that but it creating border of the circle.

Comment: Canvas canvas=new Canvas();
        final int strokeWidth = 5;
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setTextSize(18);
        canvas.drawText("10", 0, 10,15, 30, paint);
        rect = new RectF(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, 100 + strokeWidth, 100 + strokeWidth);
        angle = 30;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172930/discussion-between-vipin-nu-and-faran-javed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

```
public class Circle extends View {

    private static final int START_ANGLE_POINT = 30;

    private final Paint paint;
    private final RectF rect;
    private float angle;

    public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        final int strokeWidth = 5;
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

        paint.setTextSize(30);
//        new Canvas().drawText("10", 5, 10,15, 30, paint);
        rect = new RectF(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, 100 + strokeWidth, 100 + strokeWidth);
        angle = 30;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, START_ANGLE_POINT, angle, false, paint);
//        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, 200, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        canvas.drawText("10", 15, 30  , paint);

    }

    public float getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

 paint.setColor(Color.rgb(110, 110, 110));

 paint.setTextSize(whiteKeyTextSize);

 canvas.drawText(mText, start, end,x, y, paint);
```

Comment: Care to explain your answer?

Comment: I did the same.I have mentioned this above.